# I want to know how it will act when the function "add" return a reference to local variable , but it run correctly, no crash

Tags: c++

please look at this code firstly .  I run it on g++ complier.
I want to know how it will act when the function "add" return a reference to local variable ,
but it run correctly, no crash . Why ?

```
int & add (int a,int b) {
   int c = a + b ;
   return c ; 
}
int main()
{
   cout<<add(1,2)<<endl;
   int a = add(1,2);
   cout<<a<<endl;
}
```

Comment: It is undefined behavior. Most of the times for smaller programs like this it works but when u take complex programs  using heavy memory and recursive etc it is undefined behavior.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because it is undefined behavior. You can't rely on it working and as your code grows it won't.

Answer (score 3):

Do not return a reference to a local variable.

It may or may not work.

But will sometime down the line it will bite you.